# Pass variable to callback - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a simple Messenger bot, using unofficial Facebook Chat API (https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api) and Node.js.

For now, I'm working on sending messages to specific users, on a specific time. Here's part of my code:

```
if(msgdate.getTime() <= currdate.getTime()){

    console.log(alarms[i].message);
    // output: test

    api.getUserID(alarms[i].user, (err, users) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);

        api.sendMessage(alarms[i].message, users[0].userID);
        // TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    });
}
```

And, my question is: how could I pass *alarms* array to this callback, so I'd be able to send message to a specific user?

Comment: Try to use `async/await`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that you change `i` variable somewhere, and because of that when callback is called `alarms[i]` is undefined. You need to store `alarms[i]` in a new variable and use it in callback:

```
let alarm = alarms[i];
api.getUserID(alarm.user, (err, users) => {
  if(err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  api.sendMessage(alarm.message, users[0].userID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Appear that you are using for loop outside. Try pass your var that way:

```
var alarm = alarm[i];
(function (alarm) {
    if(msgdate.getTime() <= currdate.getTime()){

    console.log(alarm.message);
    // output: test

    api.getUserID(alarm.user, (err, users) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);

        api.sendMessage(alarm.message, users[0].userID);
        // TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    });
})(alarm);
```

Maybe you need to pass other vars too. Just put a comma and other var, example:

```
(function (alarm, user){
    // your code here
})(alarm, user);
```